# when wishing someone a happy birthday is a comma used before their name?

Tags: oxford-comma

When wishing someone a happy birthday is a comma used before their name?

Happy Birthday, John

Happy Birthday John

Comment: Either is perfectly fine.  The comma is slightly more formal.

Comment: Hello, Del. Welcome to ELU and thank you for participating. I believe you will find that your question has been answered previously and someone will likely soon provide you with a link to that answer. In the meantime, there’s a lot to learn about the site, like how to ask a good question or provide a good answer. I’d recommend you start by taking the [**tour**](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). Have fun, and we’ll see you around.